# Binding 2 Lists to to a comboBox without make a 3rd list, containing the other 2

Tags: c#, .net, datasource, controls

I want to have 2 Lists and want them to be the DataSource of my combobox,
is there a way to do this without having a 3rd list combining the other 2 lists on every change like:

```
    List<string> list1 = new List<string>(),
        list2 = new List<string>(),
        list3 = new List<string>();

    private void Init()
    {
        comboBox1.DataSource = list3;
    }

    private void ListsChanged()
    {
        list3.Clear();
        list3.AddRange(list1);
        list3.AddRange(list2);
    }
```

Comment: you could do try: `comboBox1.DataSource = list1.Concat(list2);`

Comment: Nice one, thank you

Comment: i'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good example of a reason you might want to consider switching to WPF. The WPF API has this functionality built-in, in the form of the `CompositeCollection` class.

That said, it is possible to achieve similar effect in Winforms. You "just" have to write your own binding source implementation that can aggregate existing sources. I put "just" in quotes, because correctly implementing a binding source in a fully-functional way is non-trivial.

That said, here's an example that would work for simple cases (i.e. those that don't involve sorting the source data):

```
class CompositeBindingList<T> : IList<T>, IBindingList, ICancelAddNew
{
    private const string _kstrIndexOutOfRange = "index must be non-negative and less than Count";
    private readonly List<BindingList<T>> _sources = new List<BindingList<T>>();

    #region CompositeBindingList<T>-specific members

    public void AddBindingList(BindingList<T> list)
    {
        list.AddingNew += _OnAddingNew;
        list.ListChanged += _OnListChanged;
        _sources.Add(list);
        ListChanged?.Invoke(this, new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.Reset, 0));
    }

    public void RemoveBindingList(int index)
    {
        _sources.RemoveAt(index);
        ListChanged?.Invoke(this, new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.Reset, 0));
    }

    public int BindingListCount
    {
        get { return _sources.Count; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region BindingList-mirroring members

    public event AddingNewEventHandler AddingNew;

    public T AddNew()
    {
        if (_sources.Count == 0)
        {
            _sources.Add(new BindingList<T>());
        }

        return _sources[_sources.Count - 1].AddNew();
    }

    #endregion 

    #region IList<T> members

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get { return _sources[_GetSourceIndexOrThrow(ref index)][index]; }
        set { _sources[_GetSourceIndexOrThrow(ref index)][index] = value; }
    }

    public int Count => _sources.Sum(s => s.Count);

    public bool IsReadOnly => _sources.Cast<ICollection<T>>().All(s => s.IsReadOnly);

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        if (_sources.Count == 0)
        {
            _sources.Add(new BindingList<T>());
        }

        _sources[_sources.Count - 1].Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear() => _sources.Clear();

    public bool Contains(T item) => _sources.Any(s => s.Contains(item));

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        foreach (BindingList<T> source in _sources)
        {
            source.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
            arrayIndex += source.Count;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => _sources.SelectMany(s => s).GetEnumerator();

    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        var (source, index, baseIndex) = _GetIndexOf(item);

        return index >= 0 ? baseIndex + index : -1;
    }

    private (BindingList<T> source, int index, int baseIndex) _GetIndexOf(T item)
    {
        int baseIndex = 0;

        foreach (BindingList<T> source in _sources)
        {
            int index = source.IndexOf(item);

            if (index >= 0)
            {
                return (source, index, baseIndex);
            }

            baseIndex += source.Count;
        }

        return (null, -1, -1);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        int sourceIndex = _GetSourceIndex(ref index);

        if (sourceIndex == -1)
        {
            if (index != 0)
            {
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException(_kstrIndexOutOfRange);
            }

            sourceIndex = _sources.Count - 1;
            index = _sources[sourceIndex].Count;
        }

        _sources[sourceIndex].Insert(index, item);
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        var (source, index, baseIndex) = _GetIndexOf(item);

        if (index < 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            source.RemoveAt(baseIndex + index);
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index) => _sources[_GetSourceIndex(ref index)].RemoveAt(index);

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();

    #endregion

    #region ICollection members

    object ICollection.SyncRoot => throw new NotSupportedException();

    bool ICollection.IsSynchronized => false;

    void ICollection.CopyTo(Array array, int index)
    {
        CopyTo((T[])array, index);
    }

    #endregion 

    #region IList members

    bool IList.IsFixedSize => _sources.Cast<IList>().All(s => s.IsFixedSize);

    object IList.this[int index]
    {
        get => this[index];
        set => this[index] = (T)value;
    }

    int IList.Add(object value)
    {
        if (value is T)
        {
            Add((T)value);
            return Count - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    bool IList.Contains(object value)
    {
        return Contains((T)value);
    }

    int IList.IndexOf(object value)
    {
        return value is T ? IndexOf((T)value) : -1;
    }

    void IList.Insert(int index, object value)
    {
        Insert(index, (T)value);
    }

    void IList.Remove(object value)
    {
        if (value is T)
        {
            Remove((T)value);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region IBindingList members

    public event ListChangedEventHandler ListChanged;

    bool IBindingList.AllowNew => _sources.All(s => s.AllowNew);

    bool IBindingList.AllowEdit => _sources.All(s => s.AllowEdit);

    bool IBindingList.AllowRemove => _sources.All(s => s.AllowRemove);

    bool IBindingList.SupportsChangeNotification => _sources.Cast<IBindingList>().All(s => s.SupportsChangeNotification);

    bool IBindingList.SupportsSearching => _sources.Cast<IBindingList>().All(s => s.SupportsSearching);

    bool IBindingList.SupportsSorting => false;

    bool IBindingList.IsSorted => false;

    PropertyDescriptor IBindingList.SortProperty => throw new NotSupportedException();

    ListSortDirection IBindingList.SortDirection => throw new NotSupportedException();

    object IBindingList.AddNew()
    {
        return AddNew();
    }

    void IBindingList.AddIndex(PropertyDescriptor property)
    {
        foreach (IBindingList list in _sources)
        {
            list.AddIndex(property);
        }
    }

    void IBindingList.ApplySort(PropertyDescriptor property, ListSortDirection direction)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    int IBindingList.Find(PropertyDescriptor property, object key)
    {
        int baseIndex = 0;

        foreach (IBindingList list in _sources)
        {
            int index = list.Find(property, key);

            if (index >= 0)
            {
                return baseIndex + index;
            }

            baseIndex += list.Count;
        }

        return -1;
    }

    void IBindingList.RemoveIndex(PropertyDescriptor property)
    {
        foreach (IBindingList list in _sources)
        {
            list.RemoveIndex(property);
        }
    }

    void IBindingList.RemoveSort()
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    #endregion

    #region ICancelAddNew

    public void CancelNew(int itemIndex)
    {
        _sources[_sources.Count - 1].CancelNew(itemIndex);
    }

    public void EndNew(int itemIndex)
    {
        _sources[_sources.Count - 1].EndNew(itemIndex);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private implementation details

    private void _OnListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int baseIndex = 0, sourceIndex = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < _sources.Count; i++)
        {
            if (_sources[i] == sender)
            {
                sourceIndex = i;
                break;
            }

            baseIndex += _sources[i].Count;
        }

        if (sourceIndex == -1)
        {
            throw new Exception("internal exception -- unknown sender of ListChanged event");
        }

        ListChangedEventArgs e2;

        switch (e.ListChangedType)
        {
            case ListChangedType.ItemAdded:
            case ListChangedType.ItemChanged:
            case ListChangedType.ItemDeleted:
                e2 = new ListChangedEventArgs(e.ListChangedType, e.NewIndex + baseIndex);
                break;
            case ListChangedType.ItemMoved:
                if (e.PropertyDescriptor != null)
                {
                    e2 = new ListChangedEventArgs(e.ListChangedType, e.NewIndex + baseIndex, e.PropertyDescriptor);
                }
                else
                {
                    e2 = new ListChangedEventArgs(e.ListChangedType, e.NewIndex + baseIndex, e.OldIndex + baseIndex);
                }
                break;
            case ListChangedType.PropertyDescriptorAdded:
            case ListChangedType.PropertyDescriptorChanged:
            case ListChangedType.PropertyDescriptorDeleted:
                e2 = new ListChangedEventArgs(e.ListChangedType, e.PropertyDescriptor);
                break;
            case ListChangedType.Reset:
                e2 = new ListChangedEventArgs(e.ListChangedType, e.NewIndex + baseIndex);
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("invalid value for e.ListChangedType");
        }

        ListChanged?.Invoke(this, e2);
    }

    private void _OnAddingNew(object sender, AddingNewEventArgs e)
    {
        AddingNew?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    private int _GetSourceIndexOrThrow(ref int index)
    {
        int sourceIndex = _GetSourceIndex(ref index);

        if (sourceIndex >= 0)
        {
            return sourceIndex;
        }

        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException(_kstrIndexOutOfRange);
    }

    private int _GetSourceIndex(ref int index)
    {
        int sourceIndex = 0;

        while (sourceIndex < _sources.Count && index > _sources[sourceIndex].Count)
        {
            index -= _sources[sourceIndex].Count;
            sourceIndex++;
        }

        if (sourceIndex < _sources.Count)
        {
            return sourceIndex;
        }

        return -1;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Notes:

1. The above requires that your original data are contained in `BindingList<T>` objects, rather than `List<T>` objects. The reason for this is mainly that it doesn't really make sense to try to do this sort of thing with `List<T>` objects, because `List<T>` doesn't provide any sort of list-changed notification, and so there wouldn't be an efficient way to have controls bound to the data update themselves anyway.
2. This implementation makes use of the new value tuple feature in C#. To compile this code, you'll need to be using C# 7, and will need to use the NuGet Package Manager to install the System.ValueTuple package.

The implementation above maintains a collection of source `BindingList<T>` objects, and implements the same interfaces that `BindingList<T>` does. It proxies operations made on it to the appropriate source list, and when changes occur in any of the source lists, it raises the appropriate events for the binding to a `DataSource` property to work.

I attempted to implement the `Add()` and `ICancelAddNew` interface stuff correctly. This would be useful when using this with e.g. `DataGridView`. But, I did not bother to test any of that part of the code, as it's not directly relevant to your question.

Note that I did *not* implement any of the sorting features. Doing so would require a lot more overhead, including the need for an additional layer of indirection between the implementation and the source lists it uses (i.e. to maintain the sorted view of the aggregated data).

I *did* actually implement a lot more than was strictly necessary. I could have just thrown `NotSupportedException()` in any of the mutation members (insert, add, remove etc.) and required all modifications to go through the original source lists. Then the above would merely forward the `ListChangedEvent`. But, where's the fun in that? :)

Once you've added the above class to your project, using it very simple. Just create an instance of this class, call `AddBindingList()` with each source `BindingList<T>` object you want to include, and then set your `comboBox1.DataSource` to this new `CompositeBindingList<T>` instance. Any changes, either to the `CompositeBindingList<T>` or its source lists, will be observed by the control and its contents updated to match. (Modifying the `CompositeBindingList<T>` object will modify one of the underlying source lists accordingly.)

See below for a full Winforms sample.

For what it's worth, if you're stuck with `List<T>` as your source list objects, you might as well just recreate the data source from scratch any time the source lists change. Which, by the way, you could do with something like:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = list1.Concat(list2).ToArray();
```

As promised, here's the full Winforms code to demonstrate (not including the `Program` class…I assume you can get that set up on your own):

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly BindingList<string> _list1 = new BindingList<string>();
    private readonly BindingList<string> _list2 = new BindingList<string>();
    private readonly CompositeBindingList<string> _composite = new CompositeBindingList<string>();
    private readonly ViewModel _model = new ViewModel();

    class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _index;
        public int Index
        {
            get { return _index; }
            set { _UpdateField(ref _index, value); }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void _UpdateField<T>(ref T field, T newValue,
            Action<T> onChangedCallback = null,
            [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, newValue))
            {
                return;
            }

            T oldValue = field;

            field = newValue;
            onChangedCallback?.Invoke(oldValue);
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", _model, "Index", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);

        listBox1.DataSource = _list1;
        listBox2.DataSource = _list2;

        _composite.AddBindingList(_list1);
        _composite.AddBindingList(_list2);

        listBox3.DataSource = _composite;
        comboBox1.DataSource = _composite;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _list1.Add($"_list1: {_list1.Count + 1}");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _list2.Add($"_list2: {_list2.Count + 1}");
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.DataSource = _list2.Concat(_list1).ToArray();
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _composite.Insert(_model.Index, $"global: {_composite.Count + 1}");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.listBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
        this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.listBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
        this.comboBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
        this.listBox3 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
        this.button3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.button4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 13);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(160, 53);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.button1.Text = "Add";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        // 
        // listBox1
        // 
        this.listBox1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)));
        this.listBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.listBox1.IntegralHeight = false;
        this.listBox1.ItemHeight = 31;
        this.listBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 72);
        this.listBox1.Name = "listBox1";
        this.listBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(315, 506);
        this.listBox1.TabIndex = 1;
        // 
        // button2
        // 
        this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(343, 12);
        this.button2.Name = "button2";
        this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(160, 53);
        this.button2.TabIndex = 0;
        this.button2.Text = "Add";
        this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
        // 
        // listBox2
        // 
        this.listBox2.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)));
        this.listBox2.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.listBox2.IntegralHeight = false;
        this.listBox2.ItemHeight = 31;
        this.listBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(343, 71);
        this.listBox2.Name = "listBox2";
        this.listBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(315, 507);
        this.listBox2.TabIndex = 1;
        // 
        // comboBox1
        // 
        this.comboBox1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.comboBox1.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        this.comboBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.comboBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(729, 20);
        this.comboBox1.Name = "comboBox1";
        this.comboBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(286, 39);
        this.comboBox1.TabIndex = 2;
        // 
        // listBox3
        // 
        this.listBox3.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.listBox3.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.listBox3.IntegralHeight = false;
        this.listBox3.ItemHeight = 31;
        this.listBox3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(674, 72);
        this.listBox3.Name = "listBox3";
        this.listBox3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(338, 506);
        this.listBox3.TabIndex = 1;
        // 
        // button3
        // 
        this.button3.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.button3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(574, 12);
        this.button3.Name = "button3";
        this.button3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(149, 53);
        this.button3.TabIndex = 3;
        this.button3.Text = "Refresh";
        this.button3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button3.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button3_Click);
        // 
        // button4
        // 
        this.button4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 598);
        this.button4.Name = "button4";
        this.button4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(177, 52);
        this.button4.TabIndex = 4;
        this.button4.Text = "Add Global";
        this.button4.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button4.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button4_Click);
        // 
        // textBox1
        // 
        this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(195, 606);
        this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
        this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(154, 38);
        this.textBox1.TabIndex = 5;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(16F, 31F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1027, 660);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button4);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button3);
        this.Controls.Add(this.comboBox1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.listBox3);
        this.Controls.Add(this.listBox2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.listBox1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox listBox1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox listBox2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox comboBox1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox listBox3;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button3;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button4;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
}
```